# Create hundreds of documents at once?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, document

I would like to create a couple hundred documents at once for a test I am writing and I was wondering if this is possible. Format doesn't matter necessarily but I would prefer PDF. Content doesn't have to be unique either so it can be the same document so is it possible to do this without copy and pasting a hundred times? All documents will be stored locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using python 3:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    newfile = open("file" + str(i) + '.pdf', "w")
    newfile.write("I am some text")
    newfile.close()
```

Literally, this alone in a .py file, run that in cmd line:

```
python3 filename.py
```

Comment: If you don't have python3 installed, on linux it's simple enough, on windows it's https://www.python.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a template PDF and then write a script which copies this file into a folder under different names.